# Using phone number as login: How to prevent people from registering with another phone number?

Tags: android, security

I want users to register their device on my web service using their phone number.

I can make sure they own the number they enter into the application by verifying against an SMS (ala WhatsApp). Then the app will at least behave.

But how do I prevent people from just listening to the data being sent to the server, modify it and use another phone number? Then they can register with whatever phone number they want.

I can encrypt the data before sending it out of the app, but all the source code can be decompiled from the APK and the code used for encrypting can just be retrieved.

So how do I do this securely?

Comment: So you envision the following sequence: 1) App asks for phone number.  2) User provides random number.  3) Service texts random number.  4) User somehow intercepts text to random number?

Comment: I was actually envisioning the app sending the SMS to itself. I believe that is how WhatsApp does it. It sends and SMS to the number provided and reads it. The server cannot generate a secret then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app says to the webservice, "send an activation code for 555-555-5555"

The web service says, "ok", then sends an SMS to 555-555-5555 with a secret code that is generated and expires in a reasonable time.

The user types the code into the app, which sends the server the secret code, and the web service marks that phone as "verified".

The user cannot listen in on what the secret code is, because it is sent only to the specific phone. If the user has sufficient resources, it could possibly intercept this... but you have to ask... why? The best you can do is increase security to a reasonable amount, you cannot prevent any possible vulnerability, but you should make a strong effort.

Comment: I was actually envisioning the app sending the SMS to itself. I believe that is how WhatsApp does it. It sends and SMS to the number provided and reads it. The server cannot generate a secret then.

Comment: There is no logic in verifying the app with itself. It works the same way as activating your account with an email. The webserver doesn't email itself, it emails you a secret code/link. That is how you do multi-factor authentication. Trying to do it inside of the app is only one factor. Check out the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-factor_authentication) on it.

Comment: Okay. Sounds like it's the way to go then. I was just sure WhatsApp sends an email within the app to itself. Thanks for your answer.